# Scripted Export of Enterprise Architect Model

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am working on a model which is stored in a Postgresql Database. There exists a eapx file, to access this model.
Is it possible to write a script, to automatically export the Model to XML Files or similar, to create a regular snapshot?

Comment: Do you mean something like starting EA with in argument the eapx file to load an option(s) asking it to generate XMI file then exit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `EA.Project.ProjectTransfer()` to export model to an eap(x) file.

Here's an example vbs script that can be executed by double-clicking it in the the windows explorer.

```vb
option explicit 
 
' Purpose: Automated Project Transfer from DBMS to EAP file as weekly backup. See end of script for different databases that are backed up.

const logPath = "C:\shares\Backups\LogFile\"
const backupPath = "C:\shares\Backups\"

sub main
    EADEV
    MsgBox ("Back-up Finished.")
end sub


sub EADEV

    Dim CurrentDate
    Currentdate = (Year(Date) & (Right(String(2,"0") & Month(Date), 2)) & (Right(String(2,"0") & Day(Date), 2)))  'yyyymmdd'

    dim repository
    dim projectInterface
    set repository = CreateObject("EA.Repository")

    Dim FileName
    Filename = "EA_Export.eap"
  
    dim LogFilePath
    LogFilePath = logPath&CurrentDate & " EA DEV (back-up).log"

    dim TargetFilePath
    TargetFilePath = logPath & "EA_Export.eap"

    dim eapString
    eapString = "DBType=1;Connect=Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DB_Name;Data Source=ServerName;LazyLoad=1;"

    'get project interface
    set projectInterface = repository.GetProjectInterface()

    projectInterface.ProjectTransfer eapString, TargetFilePath, LogFilePath

    'close EA
    repository.Exit 

    Dim newFilename 
    newFilename = backupPath & CurrentDate & " EA DEV (back-up).eap"

    Dim Fso
    Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Fso.MoveFile TargetFilePath, newFileName
   
end sub

main
```

In order to know what to put in the `eapString` you can connect to your database project and then save as a shortcut.

[image]

Then open the resulting file in a text editor and you'll find the connection string you need.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I had to remove the ´´´ at the end, to make it run. Unfortunately it still does not export anything. I have put the script next to the model file "EA_Export.eap"
I'll try to debug, but this is the first time I'm doing this in .vbs. 
I already tried to copy the string from the eap file into eapString but this didn't seem to fix it.
The script definitely would do what I asked for.

Comment: You have to make sure you define the `eapString` correctly. Easiest way is to save you project as shortcut file, and then open it with notepad. The connection string will be right there.